# Analogue of nsIClassInfo for objects created using WebIDL in Firefox (C++)?

Tags: c++, firefox, porting, gecko, webidl

I use Gecko SDK to build a C++ tool to inspect web pages (along with their internals) opened in Firefox. I use nsIClassInfo to get information on properties and methods (with their parameters) of inspected objects and it works great. Firefox is now moving to the usage of WebIDL and it removes class info for converted objects. Is there a similar way to get full information about the WebIDL interfaces at run-time using C++ code?

Answer (score 0):

[OwningNonNull](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/WebIDL_bindings#OwningNonNull) fits the bill:

> OwningNonNull is a struct declared in BindingUtils.h and exported to mozilla/dom/BindingUtils.h that is used to represent non-null C++ objects and holds a strong reference to them.  It has a conversion operator that produces T&.